# Error "The type or namespace name 'IUCompositionService' could not be found..." while using Catel.Extensions.Prizm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, catel

I try to use Catel.Extensions.Prism in my WPF MVVM Catel application developed in MS VS 2015 Professional. But when I use IUCompositionService interface then the following error has place: "*The type or namespace name 'IUCompositionService' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*". I've installed the last stable version of Catel.Extensions.Prism via NuGet in my project and add to MainWindowViewModel class the following code:

```
using Catel.Extensions.Prism;

// This is command method realizing switch to specified View.
private void ShowCalibrationViewExecute() 
{
     var ViewModel = new CalibrationViewModel(); // ViewModel for specified View.
     var dependencyResolver = this.GetDependencyResolver();
     var uiCompositionService = dependencyResolver.Resolve<IUCompositionService>(); // Error!
     . . . . . . .
}
```

And in the line

```
var uiCompositionService = dependencyResolver.Resolve<IUCompositionService>();
```

I have the error: "The type or namespace name 'IUCompositionService' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)". Why this error has place? What I've done wrong? Please help me to correct this error.

Answer (score 1):

It's IUICompositionService (you are missing an I after the U).

Comment: You spelled it wrong.  It's `UICompositionService`.  He's copied code from the docs, which is also bugged.

Comment: I think he isn't interested in the actual implementation, just the interface when resolving it from an IoC container.

Comment: I thought about that, but I couldn't find any docs suggesting UICompositionService implements an interface.  If it does, then that's fine.

Comment: I bag your pardon but what I should use in my case: the interface (IUICompositionService) or the implementation (UICompositionService)? Please specify.